# Shared Preferences Crushed on android studio project

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have created a project on android studio for register and logging in. I Use Shared Preferences for keeping the user logged in. So when i login the user i use a Toast to make sure of it. The toast does not apear.

SharedPreManager class:

```
public class SharedPreManager {
private static SharedPreManager mInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static Context mCtx;

private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME="mysharedpref12";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME="name";
private static final String KEY_ID="id";
private static final String KEY_SURNAME="surname";
private static final String KEY_AGE="age";
private static final String KEY_IDENTITY="identity";

private SharedPreManager(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;

}

public static synchronized SharedPreManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new SharedPreManager(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public boolean userLogin(int id, String username, String surname, String identity) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putInt(KEY_ID, id);
    editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
    editor.putString(KEY_SURNAME, surname);
    editor.putString(KEY_IDENTITY, identity);
    editor.apply();
    return true;
}
```

Login class:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText UsernameET, PasswordET;
CheckBox identity_doctor, identity_patient;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private int identityId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if ( SharedPreManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class));
        return;
    }

    UsernameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
    PasswordET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    identity_doctor = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_doctor);
    identity_patient = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_patient);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
}

public void OnLogin(View view) {
    final String username = UsernameET.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = PasswordET.getText().toString().trim();

    //progressDialog.show();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.login_url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {

                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                        if(!object.getBoolean("error")){
                            //that means the user successfully authenticated

                            if(SharedPreManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(object.getInt("id"),
                                    object.getString("name"),
                                    object.getString("surname"),
                                    object.getString("identity"))){
                                Toast.makeText(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        "TRUE",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                ).show();
                            }
                            SharedPreManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                                    .userLogin(
                                            object.getInt("id"),
                                            object.getString("name"),
                                            object.getString("surname"),
                                            object.getString("identity")
                                    );
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "User successfully login",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    object.getString("message"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }

                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show();
                }
            }
    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

The problem seems to happen on userLogin method of SharedPreManager class. The toast "User successfully login" does not appear. The if statement is true.

I dont know if there is a problem with the database. If needed please comment and i will edit the post with database code. Any ideas?

Logcat:
`10-05 19:18:46.807 1520-1598/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for name
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization.Login$1.onResponse(Login.java:73)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization.Login$1.onResponse(Login.java:60)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-05 19:18:46.819 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-05 19:18:46.820 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-05 19:18:46.820 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-05 19:18:46.820 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-05 19:18:46.820 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-05 19:18:46.820 2523-2523/com.example.thomas.medicalappointmentorganization W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`

Comment: I assume "crushed"  means "crashed"! So please post the error stack from the logcat.

Comment: I dont see any errors. Please check

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger?  I'd recommend that, or add some logging statements to illuminate what's happening.

Comment: With some debugging i know that the userLogin method does not return true as it was supposed to. Not very familiar with debbuggers although :/

Comment: Seems to be a problem while parsing your json. You could use Gson as parser. This would be much more elegant and less vulnerable to error. Have a look on http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html

Comment: here is your problem `org.json.JSONException: No value for name`, your json don't have value for `name`, check or post your `json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was at the php file. Json response did not include "name" and "surname" on php file.

Solved by adding:

```
$response['surname']=$user['surname']
```